# a nonstop Running of my Simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

In order to plot the Eb/N0 versus BER performance of my model Simulink and bring out the output (which is a vector of bits) from simulink to workspace, I need to the complete simulation of my model. But, the simulation doesn't stop, it runs hours und hours without stop. Actually, I haven't unterstand this problem as a beginner in Matlab-simulink. But, I am quiet sure that I need to see the end of my work to be able to analyse the performance and then correct if there is a problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, Simulink writes to the workspace only once the simulation is stopped.

Comment: But my simulation doesn't stop,it works and works....with non stop.is it normal?

Comment: You need to stop the simulation to analyse the data

Comment: if my aim is to transmit the whole coded video and then analyse the different results. I don't think that a sample part of run will be sufficient to my aim.Isn't?

Comment: Other thing, I have already done that, but by using bertool, I couldn't plot anything because I have stopped the simulation, do you undrestand me?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't. I don't know what your model does or what it looks like, nor what data you are logging. I'm just trying to explain how Simulink works.

Comment: ok if you have email oder something else, I can show you what i have done. I wil be grateful to you.

Comment: I won't be able to help you much further, not having access to Simulink anymore and not knowing anything about BER, but you should probably read through this http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/export-runtime-information.html

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want to access data during simulation:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/accessing-block-data-during-simulation.html

Comment: No, I want just to see the end of my video transmission, to be able then to see the whole output file (contained bits) and compared it to my input. In addition to that, I want to plot  Eb/N0 versus BER performance of my model Simulink. Until now, I couldn't do that, any idea??